# By using php mysql create the table and retrieve the data,How to modify the data displayed in html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to the html and php, I had created the database in mysql by using the html and php,i had inserted values and retrieve the data from mysql to php,how can i modify the table means deleting the row,updating the row. 
Below is my html code:

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>STUDENT_DATA</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="1.php" method="post" >
 <center>
 sname: <input type="text" name="sname" required><br></br>
 sno:<input type="text" name="sno"><br></br>
 marks:<input type="text" name="marks"><br></br>
 class:<input type="text" name="class"><br></br>
 phno:<input type="text" name="phno" onkeypress='return event.charCode >
 = 48 && event.charCode <= 57'><br></br>
 DOB:<input type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" 
 required pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}"
 name="DOB"/><br></br>
 <button>submit</button></br>
  </center>
 </form>
```

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
if (!$connection)
 {
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
 }
$select_db = mysql_select_db( "student",$connection);
if (!$select_db)
{
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();
  $sname=$_POST['sname'];
  $sno=$_POST['sno'];
  $marks=$_POST['marks'];
  $class=$_POST['class'];
  $phno=$_POST['phno'];
  $DOB=$_POST['DOB'];
  if($sname!='' and $sno!='' and $marks!='')
  {
  $query = mysql_query("insert into hello1(sname, sno, marks, class, phno ,    
   DOB)
   values ('$sname', '$sno', '$marks', '$class','$phno','$DOB')");
   echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
   }
  else
 {
 echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
 }
 mysql_close($connection); 
 ?>
```

Is there any one to help me?

Comment: first of all retrive all data in list. and than update particular record based on particular field ex:ID. you can get demo if you try to search for it.

Comment: I had retrieve the data and it is showing the table in html

Answer (score 0):

Updation;

```
$query = "UPDATE hello1 SET column_name_1=value_1,column_2=value_2,... WHERE some_column=some_value;
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

Deletion

```
$query = "DELETE FROM hello1 WHERE some_column=some_value;
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

**This is for ur comment :**

take data from ur form, keep a unique constraint to use in where condition,
for example if the data u need to modify is "password" for username='admin', what u have to do is,

```
$query = "UPDATE hello1 SET password=$new_pw WHERE username=admin;
```

here `$new_pasword` should contain ur new pasword and `username` should be unique (if not, it will update all the rows with username as 'admin')

**This is with reference to the code which u have sent to me.**

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("UPDATE venu SET name = ?, rollnumber = ?, address = ? id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param( $name, $rollnumber, $address, $id);
```

You **cannot** update like this because you haven't specified the required row(s) for updation.
for that what u have to do is just add a where condition.

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("UPDATE venu SET name = ?, rollnumber = ?, address = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param( $name, $rollnumber, $address, $id);
```

This means, u are updating `name, adress and rollnumber` of ur table `venu`, WHERE '`id`' of 
your `row = 'the required one'`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: how can i use these updation and delete query

Comment: I have updated the code. if u still have doubt, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: understand little bit.Can u please explain the code how it works.

Comment: Its quite diff to explain everything here, Do one thing, go through this link, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp , Still after reading the tutorial if u have any doubt, let me know. i will help u out .. :)

Comment: and if this really helps, plz mark this as the correct answer.. :)

Comment: i had read the w3 school tutorials but data in my project the data should display the table in the view and in that delete update buttons, by clicking the deleting button it should delete the row

Comment: How to update the database  that was displayed in html using php

Comment: Send ur code to aravindrpillai1992@gmail.com, I will update it and send u back.

Comment: Sir, I hand send the send to your mail id can you please update the modifications

Comment: Please find the updated answer. Mistake in ur code is mentioned and corrected there.